# how to pass parameter to a jquery function from a button click in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new in .net.I'm creating my web site using asp.net mvc4. I didn't  find a solution to pass a parameter to a jquery function. this is a part of my code:

```
        $(function () {
            $("#aa").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
            $("#aa").dialog({
                showEffect: "fade",
                hideEffect: "fade",
                minimizable: true,
                maximizable: true,
                modal: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: "Yes",
                    icon: "ui-icon-check",
                    click: function (idDel) {
                        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("supp","Company",new { id= *********** })";                            
                    }
                },
```

[...]

I want to pass item.ID_company in the place of *****
Any help ?

Comment: Is this wrapped in an onclick?  Is there just one button?

Comment: $('#<%= item.ClientID %>')

Comment: As you are a new in .net riddles are more useful for you than an open text.

Comment: Yes there is button <button id="thebigshow@(item.ID_company)" onclick="function(item.ID_company)">

Answer (score 0):

First, the 'item' must have some attribute allowing it to stand out from the remaining elements of HTML, for example: name, type, id, class, data element...

So, if your 'item' has an id="IdCompany" (for example), you can get it value with this: `$("#IdCompany").val()`

I can see that you have your javascript on the html page, so possibly you can do directly `Model.ID_company` I supose

UPDATE:
Now I read that you have a button but I detect a possible bug on your onclick event. I think you want to do this:

```
onclick="function(@item.ID_company)"
```

instead

```
onclick="function(item.ID_company)"
```

with the @ you pass the value on your model property, but without that you are passing just a string. I supose too that 'function' is only for example, in that place you must have the name of the pretended function (for example: `onclick="saveId(@item.ID_company)"`) or the entire code inside the function (for example: `onclick="return confirm('The ID = @item.ID_company are saved!')"`)

**UPDATE:**

I normaly do what you want with an anchor element, like this:

```
<a class="myBt" data-url="@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { area = "", myParamter= item.myProperty })">Some text</a>
```

And then, in my JS file I do something like this:

```
$(".myBt").click(myFunction($(this)));

function myFunction(button)
{
           var urlInBt = $(button).data("url");

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 500,
                width: 700,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function () {
                        if (!isStringEmpty(urlInBt ))
                            window.location.href = urlInBt ;
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function () {
                    $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                    $("#dialog").empty();
                }
            });

        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
}
```

Depends what you want to do with url action

Comment: My problem is that I want to pass to the action "supp" which needs the parameter ID_company when I click on button "yes". And "yes" appear only if I click on this button : <button id="thebigshow@(item.ID_company)" onclick="function(@item.ID_company)"> . this is my real problem